# Isolating the EVM and calling contracts functions

Tags: go-ethereum, evm

For a project of mine I would like to run a standalone new EVM with precise specifications. 
After having instantiated and set up the vm, I have a deployed a test contract using the vm « Create » function.

However I don’t understand how to invoke specific methods of the contract using go-ethereum.

I thought I could use the Call and CallCode functions but they don’t indicate any argument concerning the methods except the input byte array.

Any help really appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is carried in the input bytes as per this the yellow paper. See here: http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf.

Much more information is here: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI. The thing you're looking for is called the `function selector` in that page.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your very useful response. I was able to find an example of your explanation in the runtime_test.go